# Problem with 64 bit R's optim under windows 7

Tags: windows, optimization, r, 64-bit

I am currently in the final phase of developing my first R package which is supposed to fit multinomial processing tree (MPT) models (see its [homepage](http://www.psychologie.uni-freiburg.de/Members/singmann/R/mptinr) for the current version). The model fitting is achieved by R's `optim` function.
Today I was playing around with it for the first time on a windows 7 machine and noticed something really strange: `optim` does not converge succesfully when using the 64 bit version of R. This looks like a bug to me (especially as `nlminb` converges for both R versions). As `optim` is at the core of my package, any help on this question is greatly appreciated.

Here comes a minimally reproducible example (normally the model is specified via expressions and not specified in the objective function, but for simplicity I put everything in the objective function here):

```
# The objective function:
llk.tree <- function (Q, data) 
{
    p <- Q[1]
    q <- Q[2]
    r <- Q[3]
    e <- rep(NA,4)
    e[1] <- p * q * r
    e[2] <- p * q * (1-r)
    e[3] <- p * (1-q) * r
    e[4] <- p * (1-q) * (1-r) + (1-p)

    llk <- sum(data * log(e))
    if (is.na(llk)) 
        llk <- -1e+19
    if (llk == -Inf) 
        llk <- -1e+19
    return(-llk)
}

# The call to optim:
optim(runif(3, 0.1, 0.9), llk.tree, data = c(24, 65, 30, 61), method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = rep(0, 3), upper = rep(1, 3))
```

This example reproduces an example from a [seminal paper on MPTs by Riefer & Batchelder](http://psy2.ucsd.edu/~dhuber/math_readings/riefer_batchelder_1988.pdf), namely row 1 in Table 1 p. 327 (expected parameter values would be p = 1, q = .49 and r = .30).

Running it on a 32 bit R **always** gives the correct result (tried with versions 2.12.2 and 2.13.0):

```
$par
[1] 1.0000000 0.4944449 0.3000001

$value
[1] 234.7110

$counts
function gradient 
      11       11 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

(Note that count may differ due to random starting values.)

Running it on a 64 bit R on the other hand may produce such a (wrong) result:

```
$par
[1] 0.8668081 0.6326655 0.1433857

$value
[1] 257.7328

$counts
function gradient 
       3        3 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

The returned value of the objective function and the returned parameter values differ on each run, but count is always 3!

Note that running `nlminb` produces correct results on 32 bit and 64 bit R:

```
nlminb(runif(3, 0.1, 0.9), llk.tree, data = c(24, 65, 30, 61), lower = 0, upper = 1)

$par
[1] 1.0000000 0.4944445 0.3000000

$objective
[1] 234.711

$convergence
[1] 0

$iterations
[1] 14

$evaluations
function gradient 
      19       55 

$message
[1] "relative convergence (4)"
```

One final note: We have examples (this is our simplest example model) that worked on 64 bit R and `optim` but more examples (like the one shown here) did not work.

And count is always 3...

**EDIT:**

When fixing the starting values (thanks to Joshua Ulrich) `optim` does not move away from those fixed values under 64 bit R:

```
optim(c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), llk.tree, data = c(24, 65, 30, 61), method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = rep(0, 3), upper = rep(1, 3))

$par
[1] 0.5 0.5 0.5

$value
[1] 276.1238

$counts
function gradient 
       3        3 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

Comment: Can you provide a value for `set.seed()` that produces the incorrect result?

Comment: running it with specified instead of random starting values produces the error on my machine e.g. .5: `optim(c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), llk.tree, data = c(24, 65, 30, 61), method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = rep(0, 3), upper = rep(1, 3))`

Comment: @ Joshua, please see my edit which makes me even more speechless...

Comment: For as far as I can see it, you ran into a bug.

Comment: @Joshua Thanks for the comment. I will wait another day for other comments here, and then post on the mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We did some more testing today and found the same problem as described in the question under Linux using 64 bit R.

However, thanks to [Joachim Vandekerckhove](http://ppw.kuleuven.be/okp/people/Joachim_Vandekerckhove/) for this ingenious idea, we tried a simple change that solved the problem (although the issue remains suspicious). At the end of the objective function if `llk` is `Inf` we set it to an extremely high value (was `1e19`).
Using a smaller value (e.g., `1e10`) removes the problem on 64 bit machines (so far tested on Linux):

```
llk.tree <- function (Q, data) 
{
    p <- Q[1]
    q <- Q[2]
    r <- Q[3]
    e <- rep(NA,4)
    e[1] <- p * q * r
    e[2] <- p * q * (1-r)
    e[3] <- p * (1-q) * r
    e[4] <- p * (1-q) * (1-r) + (1-p)

    llk <- sum(data * log(e))
    if (is.na(llk)) 
        llk <- -1e+10
    if (llk == -Inf) 
        llk <- -1e+10
    return(-llk)
}

# The call to optim:
optim(runif(3, 0.1, 0.9), llk.tree, data = c(24, 65, 30, 61), method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = rep(0, 3), upper = rep(1, 3))
```

This returns the correct result!